# How to synchronize correctly the following situation?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, synchronization, threadpool

I am creating an application for uni which emulates a client-server software for sending and receiveing emails. I want to understand if the following implementation synchronizes correctly the reading and writing on the files on server-side, it seems to work correctly, but I'm not 100% secure that it has sense. For each user I have a file of received emails and a file of sended emails.

The situation is the following, I have N tasks each of them is managed by a dedicated class, more precisely I have the following: LoginTask, ReceiveTask, SendTask and DeleteTask the codes are very similar among them so I won't put all of it.

Send Task

```
public class SendTask extends Thread implements Runnable {

private final ServerModel model;
private final Socket incoming;
private final ObjectOutputStream out;
private final ObjectInputStream in;

public SendTask(Socket s, ServerModel model, ObjectOutputStream outObj, ObjectInputStream inObj) {
    this.out = outObj;
    this.in = inObj;
    this.incoming = s;
    this.model = model;
    setDaemon(true);
}

.... some code ....

            boolean validUsers = true;
            for (String receiver : receiverToString) {
                if (!model.checkUser(receiver)) {
                    out.writeObject("false");
                    validUsers = false;
                    break;
                } 
            }

            if(validUsers) {
                model.writeSended(emailToString);
                model.writeReceived(emailToString);               
                out.writeObject("confermo");                                
            }
```

Delete Task

```
public class DeleteTask extends Thread implements Runnable {

private final ServerModel model;
private final Socket incoming;
private final ObjectOutputStream out;
private final ObjectInputStream in;
private final String user;

public DeleteTask(Socket s, ServerModel model, ObjectOutputStream outObj, ObjectInputStream inObj, String user) {
    this.out = outObj;
    this.in = inObj;
    this.incoming = s;
    this.model = model;
    this.user = user;
    setDaemon(true);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        String email = (String)in.readObject();
        String fileType = (String)in.readObject();
        String outcome = model.deleteEmail(email, user, fileType);

        out.writeObject(outcome);
        incoming.close();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DeleteTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

On the server-side I have an object named model which reads and writes on the files in order to save and load emails, each time I execute a task I pass the reference to that object like this in a class called ServerViewController:

```
                case "send":
                    Runnable sendTask = new SendTask(incoming, serverModel, outObj, inObj);
                    exec.execute(sendTask);                            
                    break;

                case "delete": 
                    String userD = (String)inObj.readObject();                        
                    Runnable deleteTask = new DeleteTask(incoming, serverModel, outObj, inObj, userD);
                    exec.execute(deleteTask);
```

Finally in my ServerModel class (referred by the model object passed from the controller to the tasks) all the signatures that read or write on a file are declared synchronized:

```
public synchronized String deleteEmail(String mail, String user, String type) throws IOException {
public synchronized void writeReceived(String[] emailToString) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
public synchronized void writeSended(String[] emailToString) throws IOException {
public synchronized ArrayList<String> loadUserReceivedEmails(String username) throws IOException {
public synchronized ArrayList<String> loadUserSendedEmails(String username) throws IOException {
```

I want to know if the model objects are synchronized among them by definition since they are the same object or if that's not the case, does my synchronization work correctly? Is it enough to declare the methods synchronized in order to manage correctly the files?

Would it be better or more reasonable to omit the synchronized in the signatures and write some blocks in the tasks classes like the following

```
synchronized(model) { ... task do your things on the model ... }
```

???

Comment: You can use here Lock interface in some place.

Comment: But is it correct what I've done? I'll watch it later and try to understand it